# Pointers to pointers

Tags: pointers

```
#include <stdio.h>
void SetupAll(int *iPtr, int **p, int ***pp, int ****ppp){
   *p = iPtr;
   **pp =iPtr;
   ***ppp = iPtr;
   printf("hi\n");
}

int main() {
   int i = 42, *p, **pp, ***ppp;
   SetupAll(&i, &p, &pp, &ppp);
   printf("%u %u %u %u\n", ***ppp, **pp, *p, i);
}
```

Why is it that when I run this code without ppp, the triple pointer, it runs prefectly fine and prints 42 three times. But, when I include the triple pointer, I get a seg fault from within the SetupAll function. In my mind, ppp follows the same format as the other two pointers to get i. Help?

Comment: When you debug, what are the raw pointer values of `p`, `pp`, `ppp` when `SetupAll` is entered into?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It crashes because you are dereferencing the pointers before you've initialized them. You have the same problem even if you don't have `ppp` -- you just got lucky and it didn't crash somehow.

What you intend to do is the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void SetupAll(int *iPtr, int **p, int ***pp, int ****ppp){
   *p = iPtr;
   *pp = p;
   *ppp = pp;
   printf("hi\n");
}

int main() {
   int i = 42, *p, **pp, ***ppp;
   SetupAll(&i, &p, &pp, &ppp);
   printf("%u %u %u %u\n", ***ppp, **pp, *p, i);
}
```

Notice the difference in SetupAll -- you are dereferencing each pointer only once, so that you can set its value. The rest of the "stars" in the declaration tell you what type of thing that pointer points to.

EDIT: To elaborate, when you do `**pp`, you are actually doing `*(*pp)` -- in other words (a) first find the value of `*pp` which is itself a pointer to an int, then (b) try to find the value of the int that `*pp` points to. But in your original code, you hadn't initialized `*pp` yet, so it pointed somewhere random. So at (b), when you try to find the value of the int, you can easily crash if the random value returned by `*pp` isn't a valid memory address.

Comment: Great answer. As supplementary, I would recommend to initialize the pointers to null when you declare them, which could avoid the "lucky" but actually "unlucky" situations: always crash might be better than don't know when to crash.

Comment: Ah, excellent point, @duskast. always crashing is definitely better than random crashing! I could add that to the answer, but probably it's clearer if the only difference to the original code is in the de-referencing.

Answer (score 0):

It can be helpful to debug this problem with valgrind, a tool for unmasking memory errors.

Compile it with debug symbols and run it under valgrind:

```
$ cc test.c -o test -g 
$ valgrind ./test 
[...]
Use of uninitialised value of size 8
   at 0x100000E85: SetupAll (test.c:4)
   by 0x100000ED3: main (test.c:11)
Invalid write of size 8
   at 0x100000E85: SetupAll (test.c:4)
   by 0x100000ED3: main (test.c:11)
Address 0x0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
```

Line 4 is this:

```
   **pp =iPtr;
```

So you can see that valgrind terminated the program when you tried to dereference `*p`, an uninitialized value.